# Knowing the optical path difference, how do I calculate the resulting image?

Tags: optics, optical-materials

Let's say I'm taking a picture through a cube of some material where the index of refraction varies in a known way, such as a GRIN lens. I can calculate the optical path difference as a function of position of the image plane. So I know $OPD(x,y)$. What I'm trying to do is calculate what the image would look like when viewed through this material. So if I take a grayscale image, how would the pixel values be modified given $OPD(x,y)$. Which equations and what other pieces of information do I need to do that calculation. Thanks.